How do we handle a situation when manager deliberately wants to spoil your hard work
my manager ; seems to be technical but having superiority complex in his nature. now he trying to pause my PR and gives un necessary comments and not once but once i fixed the code and then comment on other files which were already present in the PR
he tried to put pressure and assign story and when asked to reduce the scope then asking why this will take so much time; even I explained but he just keep turning down in front of team.
raise the issue with their manager but no response.
I want to understand how to tacke such situation when manager trying to put you in solidarity and unnecessarily hold the work and later when year end review will come then say your storied getting carry forward

Why would they single you out?

AFAIK I do oppose their wrong doings and raise voice against something technically wrong. given legit suggestion on team members PR and they said that reviewing PR will delay the work while they hold mine PR.

I tried to clear out many technical discussions with manager but none works. for eg. once he said  is getting deprecated so do not use; sometime say switch case are getting deprecated. using old code pattern while new methods are there. do not understand the technology but gives lecture. when I asked for the suggestion how to fix then he started scolidng that you are senior; you should know this. I said if I have known then why whould I have asked on first place. just try to represent himself superior.

So you've been arguing with them over technical details and now think that them arguing back is "deliberately spoiling your hard work"? Does that sum the situation correctly? If so, that seems like a simple and common case where you need to learn to pick your battles, and stop arguing technical minutia with your boss, just do as being told.

This is one of instances but problem is that he doesn't help how to write it but want thing done in his style

So why not just do things in his style? He is the boss, not you.

He is the manager not boss but my thoughts thsr I work for betterment of company, if I don't do it with honesty and what is good for future of the company then what is my role and responsibilities as a developer? Just following the wrong instructions? Is it

Based on the ever helpful comments:

This is one of instances but problem is that he doesn't help how to write it but want thing done in his style

and

AFAIK I do oppose their wrong doings and raise voice against something technically wrong. given legit suggestion on team members PR and they said that reviewing PR will delay the work while they hold mine PR.

I think the problem you are facing has nothing to do with "spoiling your hard work" and all to do with learning to pick your battles.

That makes a great meme, but is hardly a recipe for workplace success where it doesn't matter how "right" you are if no one will listen to you. Notably the "right" in the workplace is also a much broader concept than "this is technically false", because while method X may truly be better than Y in purely technical context, that ignores anything about the bigger picture.
Do you know who knows that bigger picture? Your boss.
But you didn't explain how you went on and tried to understand them better, just went right into arguing and, well, now are not enjoying when you get argued back while the boss also wields the fact that they are, well, your boss as a stick.
Unless you think you can suddenly explain your view in a much more persuasive way, I would stop arguing minute technical points and just do as you are told and take this as a learning experience of when it's not worth to pick a battle.
And if you cannot, well, start job hunting, as the dynamic here is very clear.
